# This declaration has no storage or type specifier

Tags: c, storage-class-specifier

I have this function:

```
void bs_gmm(IMG in_img,struct bs_gmm_var *gmm_ctxt,IMG *bg_msk,IMG *bg_img)
```

in which I am declaring some variables like:

```
int num_models,num_features;
float lr,update_factor;
float deviation_thresh;
int std_dev_int;
```

The thing is that when I am trying to define or use these variables — for example:

```
num_models=gmm_ctxt->num_models;
```

I am getting two errors:

1. Regarding `num_models`:

   ```
   This declaration has no storage class or type specifier
   ```
2. and `gmm_ctxt`:

   ```
   gmm_ctxt is undefined
   ```

I know that local variables are by default *auto* storage class and also I had specified the type of the variable; why do I get this type of error?

The function call is from `main()` which is in another source file.

I know that I am overseeing something. Forgive me for my ignorance.

I had declared the above mentioned function in a header file and I had included it in both the source files concerned.

The structure bs_gmm_var is declared in a header and i had included it in both the source files concerned.The declaration goes as follows

```
typedef struct bs_gmm_var
{
MEAN mean;
STD_DEV std_dev;
WEIGHT weight;
CLASSIFICATION_STATE classification_state;
RANK rank;
RANK_INDEX rank_index;

int *match_array;
float *prob_feature;

int num_models;
float lr;
float update_factor;
float deviation_thresh;
float assign_thresh,dying_thresh;
float std_dev_int;

int intialize_state;

int width;
int height;
int num_features;
int num_frames;
};
```

Then i declared a pointer to the above structure in the main function.This pointer along with another structure is sent to the following function.

The structure bs_gmm_var is defined in the function shown below:

```
void intialize_params(struct bs_gmm_var **gmm_ctxt,struct config_params bs_config_params)
{
struct bs_gmm_var *gmm_stats;
int width=bs_config_params.width;
int height=bs_config_params.height;
int num_features=bs_config_params.num_features;
int num_models=bs_config_params.num_models;

// Allocate memroy for whole structure
gmm_stats = (bs_gmm_var *)malloc(sizeof(bs_gmm_var));

gmm_stats->mean=(float*)calloc(num_models*num_features*width*height,sizeof(float));
.
    .In this way i have allocated memory for other members(from mean to prob_feature)
    .
gmm_stats->prob_feature=(float *)malloc(num_features*sizeof(float));


gmm_stats->num_models=bs_config_params.num_models;
gmm_stats->lr= bs_config_params.lr;
.In this way other members(from num_models to num_frames)are also defined
    .
    gmm_stats->num_frames=bs_config_params.num_frames;

*gmm_ctxt = gmm_stats;
}
```

As you can see this defines the structure bs_gmm_var through the pointer gmm_stats.
Now,the pointer which i had sent to the above function as the address of the structure(through the pointer gmm_stats) which is defined.That pointer i am sending it to the function:

```
void bs_gmm(IMG in_img,struct bs_gmm_var *gmm_ctxt,IMG *bg_msk,IMG *bg_img)
```

Comment: Second error points to the structure `gmmctxt` being undefined. First error surfaces because of this - since it is undefined, the member `num_models` is not having any storage or type. Can you post the definition of `gmmctxt` type and make sure its header is included?

Comment: @praveen can u show `struct bs_gmm_var` ??

Comment: I've seen this warning when doing codegolf. This program will trigger it: `a; main(){return 0;}` since the `a` variable is being declared using the *implicit int* behavior. I think we'll need to see an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) to find where you missed a declaration.

Comment: Since you define a parameter `gmm_ctxt`, it is likely that `gmmctxt` is a simple typo for `gmm_ctxt` (or vice versa).  It also appears you have problems with spelling 'update' (it isn't spelled 'updtae').  The other problem doesn't make sense given the code you show (`int num_models` appears to include a type specifier), so the problem is likely in the code you don't show.

Comment: Show us the entire function definition, not isolated bits and piece of it. If possible, delete anything that you can while still exhibiting the errors. Don't try to guess what you think we need to see; if you knew that, you would have solved the problem yourself by now.

Comment: Oh: I just noticed that there's a `num_models` as a member of the structure pointed to by `gmmctxt`; you might be running into trouble with the storage class of that if `gmmctxt` is undefined (rather than `gmm_ctxt`).  It isn't the message I'd expect, but if the compiler is confused by a prior error, it might account for the odd second error.

Comment: @ManojAwasthi i think the problem for num_models is not concerned with gmm_ctxt because some other variables(in the same function) are also giving the same error.

Comment: @Jeyaram i edited it.please have a look at it.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler i thought the same(regarding num_models) but some other variables are also giving the same error. By the way sorry for the typos.

Comment: @KeithThompson i edited. please have a look at it.

Comment: I see some new information.  What I don't see is what we asked for — namely the code starting from `void bs_gmm(...){` onwards until the line that contains the compiler error.  The line(s) with the compiler error(s) should be marked clearly; the exact errors would be useful.  We would assume that there are no other errors prior to the ones you're worried about — if there are some other errors, fix those first.  The structure definition is helpful; the initialization function is of little relevance to why `bs_gmm()` doesn't compile, but would be very relevant if there were problems at run-time.

Answer (score 0):

Both errors point to `struct bs_gmm_var` being undefined.  Make sure to include the right header file, or define the structure before that function in the code.

To confirm the definition of the structure, running the code through the preprocessor and looking at the output can help.  With `gcc` that's `gcc -E ...` using the same compiler flags (except those used for linking).

Comment: i had included the headers.i edited the code have alook at it.

Comment: hmm, that does look good.  I recommend preprocessing, as I added to the answer, and look through that to see exactly what the compiler is getting.  Make sure the struct definition is above the line on which the error occurs.  Also note that complete error messages may help.